# Java: Script to include all decimal values

Tags: java

I have some java which multiply price by 100 in order for a price to be a whole number. However in the below example, `28197.22 * 100` returns `2819700` instead of `2819722`

Code

```
oExtendedLineCost =
String.valueOf((long)(Double.valueOf(iInvoiceAmount.trim()).doubleValue()*100.0+0.5));
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript

Comment: You are concatenating `"00" ` at end of string. Why ?

Comment: sorry, this did not need to be there. I was just testing this prior.

Comment: Why are you casting a Double to a Long? That'll truncate InvoiceAmount to 28197 before the multiplication by 100.

Comment: This is where my issue lies then I believe! what would you recommend casting it to to include all the values?

Comment: The code that is currently in your question, while a bit verbose, works fine for me and produces `2819722`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got your parenthesis out of order. And, it looks like you're trying to do some rounding before you truncate to an integer.

Sometimes it helps to break a line up to see where the parenthesis fall:

```
oExtendedLineCost =
String.valueOf(
               (long)(
                      (
                       Double.valueOf(
                                      iInvoiceAmount.trim()
                                     )*100.0+0.5
                      )
                     )
              );
```

Looks like you're trying to do some "banker's rounding" where fractions of a dollar > .5 round up, but I am not certain that the cast to long will round as you expect it to. Check this out:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-round-decimal-number

Comment: Hi,This produces 28197 my side instead of 2819722.

Comment: Try it a piece at a time, building up from the inside-out. Make sure iInvoiceAmount.trim() looks right. Then Double.valueOf(iInvoiceAmount.trim())... and so on